# mysql version with apt-get too old?

Tags: linux, mysql, debian

i just installed mysql with apt-get:

```
apt-get install apache2-mpm-prefork libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server php5-mysql
```

But phpMyadmin says:

```
  Version MySQL: 5.1.49-3
```

isn't that a bit too old considering mysql is now at "[5.5.9](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/)" ?

thanks

Comment: How do you define old?  If you mean well tested and stable then it isn't to old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The packaged version for Debian is choosen at the time of freezing the distribution. After that a package only receive security updates and minor bug fixes. That makes Debian stable. You can switch to source code if you want the latest version or use the testing or unstable packaged version at your own risk.

Also think than Oracle bumped the version number from 5.1 to 5.5 so 5.1 isn't that old